# How do you make an object local using the API

Tags: python, linked-data

I'd like to make an object (currently linked to a library) local.

I know there is `bpy.ops.object.make_local` function, but is there a faster solution ?

The code below works, but needs to select the object in the scene:

```
bpy.context.scene.objects.active = bpy.data.objects['my object']
bpy.ops.object.make_local(type='SELECT_OBJECT')
```

Comment: Hi. What do you mean by *faster*? What's slow about that code?

Comment: I mean you have to select an object first, then use this function. Is there a way to do it in a single command ?

Comment: Operators are slow, they create undo steps and are generally not meant to be called directly from Python code.

Answer (score 4):

Just call [make_local()](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ID.html#bpy.types.ID.make_local) on the object.

```
ob = bpy.data.objects['my object']
ob.make_local()
```